# Destroy on blank nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to destroy a nested model if its attributes are blanked out in the form for the parent model - however, it appears that the `ActiveRecord::Callbacks` are not called if the model is blank.

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  using_access_control
  attr_accessible :bio, :name, :tour_dates_attributes
  has_many :tour_dates, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tour_dates, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:when].blank? || a[:where].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :bio, :name :presence => true

  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

and

```
class TourDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :address, :when, :where, :artist_id, :presence => true
  attr_accessible :address, :artist_id, :when, :where
  belongs_to :artist
  before_save :destroy_if_blank

  private
  def destroy_if_blank
    logger.info "destroy_if_blank called"
  end
end
```

I have a form for Artist which uses `fields_for` to show the fields for the artist's associated tour dates, which works for editing and adding new tour dates, but if I merely blank out a tour date (to delete it), `destroy_if_blank` is never called. Presumably the Artist controller's `@artist.update_attributes(params[:artist])` line doesn't consider a blank entity worth updating.

Am I missing something? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have code that says the record should be ignored if the 'where' or the 'when' is blank, on the accepts_nested _attributes line, remove the `reject_if` and your destroy_if blank will likely be called.

Typically to destroy, you would set a  `_destroy` attribute on the nested record, check out the docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Also, just used cocoon for some of this today, and thought it was awesome, https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 80):

I would keep the :reject_if block but insert :_destroy => 1 into the attributes hash if your conditions are met. (This is useful in the cases where it's not convenient to add _destroy to the form code.)

You have to do an extra check to see if the record exists in order to return the right value but the following seems to work in all cases for me.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tour_dates, :reject_if => :reject_tour, :allow_destroy => true

def reject_tour(attributes)
  exists = attributes['id'].present?
  empty = attributes.slice(:when, :where).values.all?(&:blank?)
  attributes.merge!({:_destroy => 1}) if exists and empty # destroy empty tour
  return (!exists and empty) # reject empty attributes
end
```

You could apply when *all* attributes are blank by just changing the `empty` calculation to:

```
empty = attributes.except(:id).values.all?(&:blank?)
```

Comment: this is a brilliant solution, however, you need to make sure validation is off for the associated model or it seems to fail on new records.

Comment: It shouldn't fail on new records, since the new record should not have an `id` attribute, and the nested record would be rejected and not loaded.   This solution rocks!   I modified it slightly by doing `empty = attributes.reject{|k,v| k == 'id'}.values.all?(&:blank?)` to check for all empty attributes.

Comment: Two things should be noted: 1) Checking if _all_ attribute values are blank will not work in most cases because of fields such as `created_at` and `updated_at`; 2) is is absolutely mandatory to pass in the `id` of the associated model's record, e.g. by using a `f.hidden_field :id` on a form _and_ by permitting the `id` in the controller's strong params method.

Comment: Scratch the 'thing #1' in my previous comment, this only applies when fiddling with the rails console but does not apply to controllers that won't permit `created_at` and `updated_at` in the attributes anyway.

Comment: I was having an error with the `(&:blank)` part so I replaced that with `{ |a| a.blank? }` Works like a charm. I will be using this a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I managed to do something like this today. Like @shuriu says, your best option is to remove the `reject_if` option and handle destruction yourself. `mark_for_destruction` comes in handy :

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tour_dates

  before_validation :mark_tour_dates_for_destruction 

  def mark_tour_dates_for_destruction
    tour_dates.each do |tour_date|
      if tour_date.when.blank? || tour_date.where.blank?
        tour_date.mark_for_destruction
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Steve Kenworthy's answer, no local variables.

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :tour_dates, :reject_if => :reject_tour, :allow_destroy => true

 def reject_tour(attributes)
    if attributes[:when].blank? || attributes[:where].blank?
      if attributes[:id].present?
        attributes.merge!({:_destroy => 1}) && false
      else
        true
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: in the words of Borat "it's a very nice"

Answer (score 1):

With your current code it's not possible, because of the `reject_if` option passed to `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

As Christ Mohr said, the easiest way is to set the `_destroy` attribute for the nested model when updating the parent, and the nested model will be destroyed. Refer to the docs for more info on this, or [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised).

Or you can use a gem like cocoon, or awesome_nested_fields.

To do specifically what you want, you should remove the `reject_if` option, and handle the logic in a callback inside the parent object. It should check for blank values in the tour_dates_attributes and destroy the nested model. But tread carefully...