# accepts_nested_attributes_for, reject_if and has_one relationship not working together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my model I have

```
has_one :order, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :order, reject_if: lambda { |order| order[:description].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
```

For some reason, although the reject_if is tested and returns true (I checked that with the debugger), the nested order is not destroyed.

There is a lot of writing about this phenomenon on the internet, but I can't find a solution.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Does the model trigger an `after_destroy` callback? If so, you could destroy the related `order` in that callback.

Comment: Only the order should be destroyed in case of no description, not the object itself!

Comment: That is not how `accepts_nested_attributes_for` works. Your code allows the model to set/update the `order` relation if it has a `description`. It also allows `order` to be destroyed if you set the `_destroy` attribute. According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) it will ignore the `reject_if` if you attempt to destroy the `order` relation. Over to your code: Did you try setting a `validates_presence_of :description` in the `Order` model?

Comment: I don't understand: for has_many this works as I used it now, but for has_one this doesn't work? has_one is not considered as "has at most one"?

Comment: What does your `Order` model look like?

Answer (score 3):

I finally created an intelligent "reject_if" setting the destroy flag on this specific occasion, as described in [Destroy on blank nested attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943013/destroy-on-blank-nested-attribute), but, to my own norms, this is not very "ruby", so can't imagine there is no better solution...

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :order, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda { |attributes|
  exists = attributes['id'].present?
  empty = attributes[:description].blank?
  attributes.merge!({_destroy: 1}) if exists and empty
  return (!exists and empty)
}
```

Comment: No news on this subject? I still have the same troubles in 2018 with `has_one`

Answer (score 1):

From the nested_attributes [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

> You may also set a :reject_if proc to silently ignore any new record hashes if they fail to pass your criteria.

```
params = { member: {
  name: 'joe', order_attributes: [
    { description: 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
    { description: 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' },
    { description: '', _destroy: '1' } # this will be ignored
  ]
}}
```

Any hash with a blank `description` will be completly ignored, even if it has the `_destroy` flag.

If you want to remove records with a blank description, I can think of two solutions

Option 1: remove them with a callback at your model:

```
before_save :remove_orders_without_description

def remove_orders_without_description
  orders.select{|o| o.description.blank?}.each(&:delete)
end
```

Option 2: Remove the `reject_if` option at the model definition and use JS at the view to set the `_delete` attribute appropriately

Comment: then I'd prefer to use the non-ruby way described in my own answer...  The before save, for my own feeling, is too late in the process...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :order, reject_if: lambda { |order| order[:_destroy].blank? && order[:description].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
```

Comment: Tried this, but doesn't work... I finally constructed something "working", but not very ruby according to me: see my own answer!