# Rails 4 nested form - nested models not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes, parameters

I am getting ready to give up on this... I 've searched every question on this, done multiple tests and I can't figure it out.

I am trying to create new records of a model (absences) through nested attributes (classroom -> students).

Here is a hash that I manually created and gets saved when I call

```
# hash: {"classroom"=>{"rank"=>"aaa", "grade_id"=>"", "students_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"last_name"=>"aaa", "first_name"=>"aaa", "absences_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"class_time"=>"1", "status"=>"valid"}}}}}, "id"=>"26"} 

@classroom = Classroom.find(params["id"])
@classroom.update(params["classroom"])
```

This gives me:

```
(0.5ms)  begin transaction
SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "classrooms" SET "rank" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "classrooms"."id" = ?  [["rank", "aaa"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-10 21:09:17.883875"], ["id", 26]]
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "students" ("last_name", "first_name", "classroom_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["last_name", "aaa"], ["first_name", "aaa"], ["classroom_id", 26], ["created_at", "2016-08-10 21:09:17.897997"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-10 21:09:17.897997"]]
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "absences" ("class_time", "status", "student_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["class_time", 1], ["status", "Αδικαιολόγητη"], ["student_id", 51], ["created_at", "2016-08-10 21:09:17.902018"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-10 21:09:17.902018"]]
(11.4ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

HOWEVER

when I get this hash through the form submission the update doesn't happen and no "absences" are getting created. Here is what the console looks like:

```
Processing by ClassroomsController#update as HTML 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blabla", 
"classroom"=>{"students_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"absences_attributes"=>{
"0"=>{"student_id"=>"50", "date"=>"2016/08/17", "class_time"=>"1", "status"=>"valid"}, 
"1"=>{"student_id"=>"50", "date"=>"2016/08/17", "class_time"=>"2", "status"=>"valid"}, 
"2"=>{"student_id"=>"50", "date"=>"2016/08/17", "class_time"=>"3", "status"=>"valid"}, 
"3"=>{"student_id"=>"50", "date"=>"2016/08/17", "class_time"=>"4", "status"=>"valid"}, 
"4"=>{"student_id"=>"50", "date"=>"2016/08/17", "class_time"=>"5", "status"=>"valid"}, 
"5"=>{"student_id"=>"50", "date"=>"2016/08/17", "class_time"=>"6", "status"=>"valid"}, 
"6"=>{"student_id"=>"50", "date"=>"2016/08/17", "class_time"=>"7", "status"=>"valid"}}, 
"id"=>"50"}}}, "id"=>"27"} 
Classroom Load (0.2ms) SELECT "classrooms".* FROM "classrooms" WHERE "classrooms"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 27]] 
(0.1ms) begin transaction Student Load 
(0.3ms) SELECT "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."classroom_id" = ? AND "students"."id" = 50 [["classroom_id", 27]] 
(0.1ms) commit transaction
```

Here is my Classrooms Controller

```
class ClassroomsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @classroom = Classroom.new
    @students = 30.times {@classroom.students.build}
  end

  def create
    @classroom = Classroom.new(classroom_params)
    if @classroom.save
      redirect_to @classroom
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Try again."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
  end

  def data
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
    @classroom.students.each { |student| 7.times { student.absences.build } }
  end

  def update
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
    @classroom.update_attributes(classroom_params)
    redirect_to @classroom
  end

  private
    def classroom_params
      params.require(:classroom).permit(:id, :grade_id, :rank, students_attributes: 
        [:id, :classroom_id, :first_name, :last_name, absences_attributes: 
        [:id, :student_id, :date, :status, :class_time]])
    end
end
```

### Classroom Model

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  # belongs_to :grade
  has_many :students, inverse_of: :classroom, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :students, allow_destroy: true,
  reject_if: proc { |a| [a[:first_name], a[:last_name]].any? {|b| b.blank?}}

  has_many :absences, through: :students
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :absences, allow_destroy: true,
  reject_if: proc { |a| a[:status].blank? }

  validates :rank, presence: true
end
```

### Student Model

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom, inverse_of: :students
  has_many :absences, inverse_of: :student

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :absences, allow_destroy: true,
  reject_if: proc { |a| a[:status].blank? }

  # validates :first_name, presence: true
  # validates :last_name, presence: true

  def full_name
    return last_name + " " + first_name
  end
end
```

### Absence Model

```
class Absence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, inverse_of: :absences

  # validates :date, presence: true
  # validates :class_time, presence: true
  # validates :status, presence: true, inclusion: { in: ["valid",
  #   "invalid", "erased"] }
end
```

I have turned off all validations as to be sure this is not the reason they are not being saved.

### Nested form view

```
<div id="absences" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <h3>Absences</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group date col-md-3" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= form_for @classroom do |class_f| %>
    <% @classroom.students.each do |student| %>
      <div class="student_<%= student.id %>">
        <h4><%= student.full_name %></h4>
        <div class="absences">
          <p>
            <% 7.times do |i| %>
              <span><%= i + 1 %></span>
            <% end %>
          </p>
          <%= class_f.fields_for :students, student do |student_f| %>
            <% student.absences.each_with_index do |absence, i| %>
              <div class="school-hour text-center" data-value="<%= i + 1 %>">
                <%= fa_icon "plus" %>
                <%= fa_stacked_icon "plus", base: "circle-o" %>
                <%= fa_icon "minus" %>
                <%= student_f.fields_for :absences, absence do |ab_f| %>
                  <%= ab_f.hidden_field :student_id, value: absence.student_id %>
                  <%= ab_f.hidden_field :date, class:"input-absence-date" %>
                  <%= ab_f.hidden_field :class_time, value: i + 1 %>
                  <%= ab_f.hidden_field :status, class:"input-absence-status" %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= button_to "Submit", "#", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

The hidden fields without values are getting filled via javascript before form submission. I don't think that relates to the problem though. The params hash comes through, but the absences are not saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was the reject_if on the classroom model.

I was trying to update the `absence` through the `user`, I wasn't actually changing the name of the `user`, and so not passing it as a param. As a result the record didn't pass the `reject_if: proc { |a| [a[:first_name], a[:last_name]].any? {|b| b.blank?}}` so it didn't reach the absence record at all. I tried putting a :new_record? validation in the reject if along with the other checks, but that didn't work out.

I found the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13774269/5909738
Awesome and clean. Look at the comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without having spent a lot of time looking at this, could this be the problem?

```
reject_if: proc { |a| a[:status].blank? }
```

It appears the params are passing in status as `""` which `.blank?` evaluates as `true`.

Whatever your form is passing in, in your first example you have `"status"=>"valid"` but in your 2nd example from the form `"status"=>""`

Comment: Sorry I had put the wrong hash before. I edited my answer with a fully filled hash. In other words even when the status is not blank, the absences are still not saving.

Comment: After a lot of frustration I almost accidentally found out that the problem was the reject_if on the classroom model. Because I was updating the absence through the user, I wasn't actually changing the name of the user, and so not passing it as a param. As a result the record didn't pass the reject_if name blank so it didn't reach the absence record at all. Thanks for your input! :)

Comment: ok so you've solved the problem? no upvote on my answer? either way glad you fixed it.

Comment: There you go. Thanks for the input again. :)

Comment: Good work!  Might I suggest you perhaps post your own answer how you fixed this in case others may find it helpful.  If you've updated your question, it may have obfuscated the cause of the problem as your original post showed `"status"=>""` in params.