# Prevent creating blank associations in nested attributes forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

I have a form with nested attributes that is sending to the Appointments controller which is creating instances of associated models called Prescriptions, Illnesses, Allergies, and Immunizations. The idea is that a doctor can fill out the form and can add information where needed, but isn't required to fill out everything (not every appointment requires a prescription).

Currently, the form sends out and creates new instances of all the associations with all the attributes blank or nil. I tried adding a validation requiring the presence of the attributes to save, but that creates an error and then nothing can save.

How can I submit one form and prevent it from creating instances of associated models if the fields for that model were empty?

Appointments Controller

```
def create
    @appointment = current_user.appointments.new(appointment_params)
    set_associations(@appointment, @patient)

    if @appointment.save
      Notification.create_appointment_notifications(@appointment, @health_profile)
      flash[:notice] = "Your appointment has been saved."
      redirect_to patient_health_profile_path(@patient, @health_profile)
    else
      flash[:notice] = "There was a problem saving your appointment, please try again."
      redirect_to patient_health_profile_path(@patient, @health_profile)
    end 



  end

  private

  def appointment_params
    symptoms = params[:appointment][:symptoms].split(",")
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    params.require(:appointment).permit(
      :diagnosis, :referrals, :notes, :symptoms,
      immunizations_attributes: [:name, :expiration_date],
      illnesses_attributes: [:name, :status],
      allergies_attributes: [:name, :status, :severity],
      prescriptions_attributes: [:medicine, :dosage, :refills, :expiration_date]
      ).merge(symptoms: symptoms,
      patient: @patient
      )
  end

  def set_associations(appointment, patient)
    appointment.illnesses.each do |illness|
      illness.patient = patient
    end

    appointment.allergies.each do |allergy|
      allergy.patient = patient
    end

    appointment.immunizations.each do |immunization|
      immunization.patient = patient
    end

    appointment.prescriptions.each do |prescription|
      prescription.patient = patient
      prescription.doctor = current_user
    end
  end

  def set_information
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @health_profile = HealthProfile.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Nested Form

```
<%= form_for @appointment do |f| %>
<div>

  <h4>Appointment</h4>  

    <div>
      <%= f.label :Symptoms %>
      <%= f.text_field :symptoms, id: "symptoms-input" %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :Notes %>
      <%= f.text_area :notes %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :Diagnosis %>
      <%= f.text_field :diagnosis %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :Referrals %>
      <%= f.text_area :referrals, id: "referrals-input" %>
    </div>

</div>

<div>

  <h4>Illnesses</h4>
  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :illnesses do |illness| %>
      <%= render "appointments/illness_fields", f: illness %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= link_to_add_association '+ Illness', f, :illnesses, partial: "appointments/illness_fields" %>
  </div>

</div>

<br>

<div>

  <h4>Allergies</h4>

  <div>
  <%= f.fields_for :allergies do |allergy| %>
    <%= render "appointments/allergy_fields", f: allergy %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= link_to_add_association '+ Allergy', f, :allergies, partial: "appointments/allergy_fields" %>
  </div>

</div>

<br>

<div>

  <h4>Immunizations</h4>

  <div>
    <div>
      <%= f.fields_for :immunizations do |immunization| %>
        <%= render "appointments/immunization_fields", f: immunization %>
      <% end%>
    </div>
    <div>
    <%= link_to_add_association '+ Immunization', f, :immunizations, partial: "appointments/immunization_fields" %>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<br>

<div>

  <h4>Prescriptions</h4>

  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :prescriptions do |prescription| %>
     <%= render "appointments/prescription_fields", f: prescription %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= link_to_add_association '+ Prescription', f, :prescriptions, partial: "appointments/prescription_fields" %>
  </div>

</div>

  <%= hidden_field_tag(:patient_id, params[:patient_id]) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:id, params[:id]) %>

<div>
  <%= f.submit :Submit %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destroy on blank nested attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943013/destroy-on-blank-nested-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Appointments Model, add this line:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :illnesses, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I needed